# I dont know why i cant loop the whole code? when i press y on "next customer"

Tags: c++, loops

I want to loop the whole codes If I press Y on "next customer"? and to reset the program just like the first try. Just type 0101 and 0307 on itemcode i put only some of my codes. define gotoxy is running only do while on "next customer " I think is the error?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define g gotoxy
main()

{
  char back_, back;
  float change, p0101 = 25.5, p0307=11,subtotal=0,total=0;
  int y=9, quantity, itemcode, cash,discount;
  clrscr();
    do{
      do{
        g(1,8);
        cout<<"Itemcode";
        g(15,8);
        cout<<"Quantity";
        g(41,8);
        cout<<"Price";
        g(51,8);
        cout<<"Subtotal";
        g(62,8);
        cout<<"Total";

        g(1,y);
        cin>>itemcode;
        g(15,y);
        cin>>quantity;
        {
          g(25,y);
          if (itemcode == 0101){
            cout<<"Yogurt(12 oz)";
            subtotal = quantity * p0101;
          }
          else if (itemcode == 0307){
            cout<<"Pumpkin (1000g)";
            subtotal = quantity * p0307;
          }
        }
        {
          g(41,y);
          if(itemcode == 0101){
            cout<<"25.50";
          }
          else if (itemcode == 0307){
           cout<<"79.75";
          }
        }
        g(51,y);
        cout<<subtotal;
        total=total+subtotal;
        g(62,y);
        cout<<total;
        subtotal=0;
        g(72,8);
        cout<<"Add item?";
        g(72,y);
        cin>>back;
        y++;
        if(back=='n'||back=='N'){
          {
            g(1,y+2);
            cout<<"CASH: ";
            cin>>cash;
          }
          if(cash>total){
            {
              g(1,y+3);
              cout<<"[R]-REGULAR\t[D] - WITH DISCOUNT    :";
            }
            cin>>discount;
            g(1,y+4);
            if(discount=='d'||discount=='D'){
              (change=cash-(.8*total));
              cout<<"Change: "<<change;
            }
            else{
              change=cash-total;
              cout<<"Change: "<<change;
            }
          }
          else if(cash<total){
            cout<<"Insufficient amount";
          }
          {
            g(18,y+8);
            cout<<"EXCHANGE OF ITEM TO ANOTHER TYPE AND SIZE IS ALLOWED,";
          }
          {
            g(18,y+9);
            cout<<"SUBJECT TO STANDARD PROVISIONS AND PRODUCT WARRANTY";
          }
          {
            g(18,y+10);
            cout<<"          PLEASE PRESENT THIS RECEIPT";
          }
          {
            g(15,y+12);
            cout<<"Next Customer?";
            cin>>back;
          }
        }
      } while(back_=='Y'||back_=='y');
    } while(back=='Y'||back=='y');
  enter code here
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: TurboC++? Check. Unformatted code? Check. `gotoxy`? Check. Code dump and poorly written question? Check.

Comment: One of the most common beginner's mistakes is putting a lot of effort into the presentation of the result and none into the presentation of the code.

Comment: That said, you should move your variable declarations inside the scope of the loop where they're relevant - the "per-customer" variables into the outer loop and the "per-item" variables into the inner loop. That will give you "fresh" variables on every iteration.

Comment: but the problem is I cant loop, my codes??  I think if }while(back=='Y'||back=='y'); wont run? or maybe have an error?

Comment: Can you give the sample inputs and desire outputs ? @JanNavasca

Comment: @molbdnilo Even better to initialize each variable to a starting value of 0 to ensure that no rogue data is inside. If it becomes possible to skip inputting a value into some of the variables, then checking for 0's on them and reprompting for input would be a great addition to this almost-complete program.

Comment: You really need to take a typing / keyboarding class if you need to use macros like `#define g(x,y) goto(x,y)`.

Comment: Please research the functions `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` so you don't have to compare with both upper and lower case letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in programs.

1. take discount type int but use as a char
2. When your takes a `integer value` and after that takes a `char`, then between these, need to use `getchar()` because at the time of getting the `integer`, you press `enter`, so need to read it.
3. When you read a `char`, check that did you take a input before it, if takes, then read the newline character by `getchar()`

Check the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char newCustomer, addItem,discount;
    float change, p0101 = 25.5, p0307=11,subtotal=0,total=0;
    int y=9, quantity, itemcode, cash;
    do{
            subtotal=0,total=0;
        do{
            cout<<"Itemcode: ";
            cin>>itemcode;
            cout<<"Quantity: ";
            cin>>quantity;
            {
            if (itemcode == 101){cout<<"Yogurt(12 oz)";
                subtotal = quantity * p0101;
            }else if (itemcode == 307){cout<<"Pumpkin (1000g)";
                subtotal = quantity * p0307;
            }}
            {
             cout<<"Price: ";
            if(itemcode == 101){
                cout<<"25.50\n";
            }else if (itemcode == 307){
                cout<<"79.75\n";
            }}
            cout<<"Subtotal: ";
            cout<<subtotal<<"\n";
            total=total+subtotal;
            cout<<"Total: ";
            cout<<total<<"\n";
            subtotal=0;
            cout<<"Add item?";
            cin>>addItem;
            getchar();
            if(addItem=='n'||addItem=='N'){
                {
                cout<<"CASH: ";
                cin>>cash;}
                getchar();
                if(cash>total){
                    {
                    cout<<"[R]-REGULAR\t[D] - WITH DISCOUNT    :";}
                    cin>>discount;
                    char c = getchar();
                    if(discount=='d'||discount=='D'){(change=cash-(.8*total));
                    cout<<"Change: "<<change<<"\n";}
                    else{change=cash-total;cout<<"Change: "<<change;}
                }
                else if(cash<total)
                {cout<<"Insufficient amount";}
                    {
                        cout<<"EXCHANGE OF ITEM TO ANOTHER TYPE AND SIZE IS ALLOWED,";
                    }
                    {
                        cout<<"SUBJECT TO STANDARD PROVISIONS AND PRODUCT WARRANTY";}
                    {
                        cout<<"          PLEASE PRESENT THIS RECEIPT\n";} {
                        cout<<"Next Customer?";cin>>newCustomer;char c =  getchar();}
            }
        }while(addItem=='Y'||addItem=='y');
    }while(newCustomer=='Y'||newCustomer=='y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: good catch on the discount. i was focusing on why it wasn't looping.

Comment: He also doesn't need `conio.h` or `stdio.h` and even if he did, it would be better to just use `cstdio` and call it a day.

Comment: thank you again Mr. David Weston :D

Comment: Is there any reason for unaccept the answer @JanNavasca ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where you input into `back_` but you have `cin>>back;` twice. Could this be your error? Your control structures are hard to follow.

You have, essentially,

```
do {
  do {
    // input some stuff for an item
    cout<<"Add item?";
    cin>>back;
    if(back == 'n' || back == 'N')
    {
      // some code to finalize the transaction
      cout<<"Next Customer?";
      cin>>back;
    }
  } while (back_=='y' || back_=='Y')
} while (back=='y' || back == 'Y')
```

You defined `back_` but never initialized it or used it in your code so when `while (back_=='y' || back_=='Y')` comes along, even when you press 'y', the loop never loops.

If you were to change the code to:

```
do {
  do {
    // input some stuff for an item
    cout<<"Add item?";
    cin>>back;
    if(back == 'n' || back == 'N')
    {
      // some code to finalize the transaction
      cout<<"Next Customer?";
      cin>>back_;
    }
  } while (back_=='y' || back_=='Y')
} while (back=='y' || back == 'Y')
```

The program would certainly loop again if you pressed 'y' but you would get some interesting behavior when you pressed 'n' for `"Add item?"` and 'y' for `"Next Customer?"`. I predict the program will close prematurely. Better to have:

```
char new_customer, add_item
do {

  //---This is the outer loop---//

  do {

    //---This is the inner loop---//

    // input some stuff for an item
    cout<<"Add another item?";
    cin>>add_item;
    if(add_item == 'n' || add_item == 'N')
    {
      // some code to finalize the transaction
      cout<<"Next Customer?";
      cin>>new_customer;
    }

    //---End of the inner loop---//

  } while (add_item=='y' || add_item=='Y')

  //---End of the outer loop---//

} while (new_customer=='y' || new_customer=='Y')
```

This way the inner loop breaks when you press 'n' at `"Add Item?"` and the outer loop breaks when you press 'n' at `"Next Customer?"`, effectively ending the program. Pressing 'y' at either will continue their respective loops.

Other odd behavior can come from

1. Pressing anything other than 'y' or 'n' at decision points
2. Inputting anything other than numbers into variables that are used to calculate prices and the such
3. Not formatting your output into the price fields with `$` or having two decimal places for money

The first two can be fixed by reading everything in as strings and then parsing it out character by character to check for valid input and then converting the appropriate strings into a numbers using built-in C++ functions. The last one can be fixed with a little fancy calculations on the data with the `%` (modulus) operator to see if the values end with a zero or not. Just some ideas.

Looks like it mostly works, except for that one major error.